# I need a starting pointo to write a Views Form handler to show a Bulk Operation view field in each row instead of a single button?

Tags: views

I have a view with a VBO field to execute a bulk operation (Get Vouchers) over nodes.

Each row has a radiobutton (I need a single selection), once you select a node you click the button "Get Vouchers" to execute the bulk operation. So far so good.

I need to show a button "Get Vouchers" in each row instead like you see in the capture below.

As Bojan Zivanovic said I need to write a  Views Form handler but I need starting pointo to write it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VBO doesn't support that.
Furthermore, in that case you probably don't even need VBO, just write a custom Views Form handler that shows the button in each row.

Comment: thanks, can you point me some doc page to learn about 'views form handler'

Comment: https://isovera.com/blog/programmatically-creating-forms-views-drupal-7

Comment: I follow the tutorial and I get the example working fine. But I have no enough knowledge to get it done with a vbo field.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a work around to skip coding. You may try using [ButtonField](http://drupal.org/project/button_field) module. It may call the needed rule. You will just need to add one more field to your content type and view.

Latter you may control button's visibility in node display via default content display options or utilizing context module for more advanced usability.

Comment: I can't see how to use it with a vbo field in a view.

Comment: If I am not mistaken VOB calls a rule or action to be executed just sometimes those rules or actions are predefined or created by some module. So by using button field you don't need VOB. Simple table view may do.

Answer (score 0):

Any field in Views can be made into a link to another page. No need for VBO or any other module. Use the `Rewrite Results` option that is included in every field's configuration form.

The following example shows how to make a simple link to another page (using the HTML anchor (a) tag), with an href attribute that points to the desired page.

If your `Get Voucher` button just redirects to the desired voucher, then this may do the trick. Use the `Replacement Patterns` to choose the field(s) you need to build the link.

> [image: Field As Link]